# How this MySQL query will be in Doctrine DQL?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have below query in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM (orders)
INNER JOIN links ON orders.ref_id = links.id
INNER JOIN users ON links.user_id = users.id
WHERE links.user_id=2
```

And three entities in Symfony: order, link, user.

How can I write this in Doctrine Query Builder?

```
            $repo = $em->getRepository('OrderBundle:Order');
            $queryBuilder=$repo->createQueryBuilder('o');
            $query = $queryBuilder
            ->select('o, l, u')
            ->innerJoin('c.ref_id', 'l')
            ->innerJoin('l.user_id', 'u')
            ->where('u.id=1')
            ->getQuery();
```

This doesn't work. I got below error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 84 near 'u WHERE u.id': Error: Class OrderBundle\Entity\Order has no association named user_id

I trying for two hours and this make me angry... Thanks in advance.

My order entity:

```
<?php
// src/OrderBundle/Entity/Order.php

namespace OrderBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\DateTime;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="orders")
 */

    class Order
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $id;


        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="OrderBundle\Entity\Order")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ref_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         */
        protected $ref_id;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
         */
        protected $date_created;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60)
         */
        protected $email;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60)
         */
        protected $email2;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */
        protected $service;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20)
         */
    protected $fromlang;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20)
     */
    protected $tolang;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    protected $academic;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=40)
     */
    protected $discipline;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $notes;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $file;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $status;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $cost;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=2)
     */
    protected $site;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->date_created = new DateTime();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateCreated
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateCreated
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setDateCreated($dateCreated)
    {
        $this->date_created = $dateCreated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateCreated
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDateCreated()
    {
        return $this->date_created;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set email2
     *
     * @param string $email2
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setEmail2($email2)
    {
        $this->email2 = $email2;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email2
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail2()
    {
        return $this->email2;
    }

    /**
     * Set refId
     *
     * @param integer $refId
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setRefId($refId)
    {
        $this->ref_id = $refId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get refId
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getRefId()
    {
        return $this->ref_id;
    }

    /**
     * Set service
     *
     * @param integer $service
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setService($service)
    {
        $this->service = $service;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get service
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getService()
    {
        return $this->service;
    }

    /**
     * Set fromlang
     *
     * @param string $fromlang
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setFromlang($fromlang)
    {
        $this->fromlang = $fromlang;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fromlang
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFromlang()
    {
        return $this->fromlang;
    }

    /**
     * Set tolang
     *
     * @param string $tolang
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setTolang($tolang)
    {
        $this->tolang = $tolang;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get tolang
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTolang()
    {
        return $this->tolang;
    }

    /**
     * Set academic
     *
     * @param boolean $academic
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setAcademic($academic)
    {
        $this->academic = $academic;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get academic
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getAcademic()
    {
        return $this->academic;
    }

    /**
     * Set discipline
     *
     * @param string $discipline
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setDiscipline($discipline)
    {
        $this->discipline = $discipline;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get discipline
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDiscipline()
    {
        return $this->discipline;
    }

    /**
     * Set notes
     *
     * @param string $notes
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setNotes($notes)
    {
        $this->notes = $notes;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get notes
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNotes()
    {
        return $this->notes;
    }

    /**
     * Set file
     *
     * @param string $file
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setFile($file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get file
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

    /**
     * Set status
     *
     * @param integer $status
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get status
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    /**
     * Set cost
     *
     * @param integer $cost
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setCost($cost)
    {
        $this->cost = $cost;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get cost
     *
     * @return \cost
     */
    public function getCost()
    {
        return $this->cost;
    }

    /**
     * Set site
     *
     * @param string $site
     *
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setSite($site)
    {
        $this->site = $site;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get site
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSite()
    {
        return $this->site;
    }
}
```

Comment: When using doctrine you use entities, not the tables as in regular SQL. Joins should be on the joined entities (need your Order entity to know what you call them). Something like `->innerJoin('c.user', 'u')`

Comment: ref_id in my order entity is http://wklej.to/9sAeR

Comment: Please add the order entity to the post.

Comment: Added. http://pastebin.com/vBHPyq4Z

Comment: Relation on @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="OrderBundle\Entity\Order") for ref_id should point to your links entity (presumably OrderBundle\Entity\Links), not order. Also, you're better off calling the property $link, then you can just ->innerJoin('c.link', 'l'), which is a lot nicer.